# How do I do this limit?

Tags: limits

I have the following equation

$$ S = 3Nk\left[ ln \left( \frac{e^{\Theta/T}}{e^{\Theta/T}-1} \right) + \frac{\Theta/T}{e^{\Theta/T}-1} \right]$$

And I need to evaulate it in the limit as $T \rightarrow 0$.

I have used the approximation $e^{\Theta/T} \approx 1 + \frac{\Theta}{T}$ (Taylor Expansion to first order).

Using this and rearranging I get that $S \rightarrow 3Nk$ but this is **incorrect.**

The **correct** answer is:

$$S \rightarrow 3Nk\frac{\Theta}{T}e^{-\Theta/T} \rightarrow 0$$

Can you explain to me why? I must be missing something here.

**EDIT:** As one of you pointed out, my professor clearly meant:
$$S \sim 3Nk\frac{\Theta}{T}e^{-\Theta/T} \rightarrow 0$$

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: You are using the expansion of the exponential at 0 while you should be interested in the limit at +oo since Theta/T goes to +oo when T goes to 0.

Comment: Furthermore, in the "correct answer" you cite, the intermediate step is absurd since it depends on T and a limit when T goes to 0 cannot depend on T.

Comment: @Did **INDEED!** This comes from my lecturer's notes. It made me wonder too; it is absurd.

Comment: Is the first $\to$ actually a $\sim$ sign?

Comment: Is $\Theta > 0$? what about $T$?

Comment: @Did Perhaps, although I can't seem to see how the intermidiate step is obtained still.

Comment: If $\to$ is $\sim$, the assertion holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- Let $x=\Theta/T$ with $\Theta\gt0$. When $T\to0^+$, $x\to+\infty$.
- When $x\to+\infty$, $\mathrm e^x/(\mathrm e^x-1)\to1$ hence $\log(\mathrm e^x/(\mathrm e^x-1))\to0$.
- When $x\to+\infty$, $x/(\mathrm e^x-1)\to0$.
- Ergo?